# How to run this query?

Tags: sql, database

I have the following table

```
MID IID

1   23

1   24

1   25

2   32

2   54

3   11

4   55

5   67
```

and i want to find all the MID's where count(IID) >1
i.e Result should be following

```
MID count(IID)

1   3

2   2
```

P.S - I tried but i am getting result for all the MID's . Here is my query

```
select distinct a.MID,count(a.IID) from Item_attribute as a group by a.MID
```

Comment: add having clause like this: "having count(a.IID)>1"

Comment: Yup it worked ..Thank you !

Comment: And you can drop that distinct too.

Comment: argh one more thing ....what  if i have to find only the MID containing the max(count(iid)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add having clause like this:

```
having count(a.IID)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING clause in SELECT statement :

```
SELECT a.MID,count(a.IID) 
FROM Item_attribute as a 
GROUP BY a.MID
HAVING COUNT(a.IID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT MID,
       COUNT( IID ) as CountIID
    FROM Item_attribute
    GROUP BY MID
HAVING COUNT( IID ) > 1;
```

For your other query please try the following...

```
SELECT MID,
       CountIID
FROM
(
    SELECT MID,
           COUNT( IID ) as CountIID
    FROM Item_attribute
    GROUP BY MID
    HAVING COUNT( IID ) > 1
) AS limitedCountIIDFinder
WHERE CountIID =  ( SELECT MAX( CountIID ) AS MaxCountIID
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT MID,
                               COUNT( IID ) as CountIID
                        FROM Item_attribute
                        GROUP BY MID
                    ) AS countIIDFinder
                  )
```

(Explanation to follow...)

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Thank You .. one more thing what if i have to find only the MID containing the max(count(iid)) ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a query that will do just that.  It will give you all the records with the top CountIID.  If you want just one, does it matter which one is chosen?

Answer (score 0):

When you'd like to have conditions on an aggregated field, you need to use `having`.
You also don't need to use distinct if you are using group by.
In your case:

```
select a.MID,count(a.IID) from Item_attribute as a group by a.MID having count(a.IID)>1
```

If you want to get the max count value then sort it descending and get top 1:

```
select top 1 a.MID,count(a.IID) 
from Item_attribute as a 
group by a.MID 
having count(a.IID)>1 
order by count(a.IID) desc
```